# jQuery append onclick function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have problem with append function.
This code doesn't work properly.

```
$(element).append("<a onclick='test('test')'> <i class='fa fa-spin fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>");
```

test function:

```
function test(value)
{
 alert(value);
}
```

I suspect that the problem is related to onclick function.

Comment: "This code doesn't work properly." is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Don't you see the problem with this portion of your code? `onclick='test('test')'`

Comment: Take a look at your pages generated HTML and you will see the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it's malformed HTML

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape apostrophes inside:

```
 $(element).append("<a onclick='test(\"test\")'> <i class='fa fa-spin fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>");
```

And make sure `test()` is defined globally (and not inside document ready for example).

Here is an example:

```js
window.test = function(value){
 alert(value);
};
$('div').append("<a onclick='test(\"test\")'>click me</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in the comments, you can't nest similar quote marks in a string like you are currently doing. You need to escape them with a back slash:

```js
function test(value) {
 alert(value);
}

var element = $('body');

$(element).append("<a onclick='test(\"test\")'> <i class='fa fa-spin fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i>Click Me</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're better off taking that inline JS out altogether and using jQuery to add the event listener (using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) because you're adding new elements to the DOM).

```
$(element).append('<a class="test">...');

$(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
  test('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ` quote instead of '

I created a jsbin here.  II  hope this is what you are trying to do

http://jsbin.com/wicanok/edit?html,js,output

```
$('#element').append("<a onclick='test(`test`)'> <i class='fa fa-spin fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'>Hi</i></a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(element).append("<a onclick='test('test')' class="your_class"> <i class='fa fa-spin fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>");
```

```
$(document).on('click',".your_class", function(){
//Write here your code!
});
```